# "BundleType must be either YAML or Json" Error using Jenkins and AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-lambda, jenkins-plugins, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy revisions to my AWS lambda functions using Jenkins and the AWS CodeDeploy add-on. I am able to build the project successfully and upload a zip of the project to an S3 bucket. At this point I receive the error:

```
BundleType must be either YAML or JSON
```

I have an appspec.yml file in my code directory. I am unsure if I need to instruct Jenkins to do something different, or if I need to instruct AWS to unzip the file and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today CodeDeploy lambda deployment only take in a YAML or JSON file as deployment revision input (which is just your AppSpec file). Today CodeDeploy Jenkins plugin needs to be updated to support uploading YAML or JSON file without zipping it: https://github.com/jenkinsci/aws-codedeploy-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/codedeploy/AWSCodeDeployPublisher.java#L230

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.